# Redcarpet + Pygments - Multiline Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-highlighting, pygments, redcarpet

I followed this Railscast to try to incorporate syntax highlighting and markdown in my Rails app:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/207-syntax-highlighting-revised?view=asciicast

But for some reason, it's only applying formatting to single line snippets.  For example, this works:

> ` `` test ``` (quotes separated to avoid github markup formatting here)

But this does not work

```

test

```

**How do I enable multi-line code snippets?**

Here is what I have in application.rb:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  class HTMLwithPygments < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
     def block_code(code, language)
      Pygments.highlight(code, lexer:language)
    end
  end

  def markdown(text)
    renderer = HTMLwithPygments.new(hard_wrap: true, filter_html: true)
    options = {
      autolink: true,
      no_intra_emphasis: true,
      fenced_code_blocks: true,
      strikethrough: true,
      superscript: true
    }
    Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, options).render(text).html_safe
  end
end
```

and my view is simply:

```
<%= markdown step.description %>
```

Note: I'm trying to do this all within a CKEditor

Comment: I am also stuck at the same issue, do you have any progress or alternative way to do this?